# libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException (Error in collection view)

Tags: ios, swift

```
2017-07-21 10:34:14.447487+0530 demo[2783:104307] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
Try this: 
    (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
    (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000009a6d0 UICollectionView:0x7fbc1b825800.width == 343   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x61000009b670 H:|-(16)-[UICollectionView:0x7fbc1b825800]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7fbc1a50d210 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x61000009a680 H:[UICollectionView:0x7fbc1b825800]-(16)-|   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7fbc1a50d210 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800009a6d0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' UIView:0x7fbc1a50d210.width == 320   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000009a6d0 UICollectionView:0x7fbc1b825800.width == 343   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView 
listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2017-07-21 10:34:14.453212+0530 demo[2783:104307] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
Try this: 
    (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
    (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
"<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x61000009bd00 _UILayoutGuide:0x7fbc1a40ae80.height == 20   (active)>",
"<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x6100000986f0 V:|-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fbc1a40ae80]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7fbc1a50d210 )>",
"<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x61000009bda0 _UILayoutGuide:0x7fbc1a40b580.height == 0   (active)>",
"<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x61000009bd50 _UILayoutGuide:0x7fbc1a40b580.bottom == UIView:0x7fbc1a50d210.bottom   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000099a00 UIButton:0x7fbc1a40a5e0'Submit'.height == 30   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000009a950 UICollectionView:0x7fbc1b825800.height == 589   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x61000009b490 V:[UIButton:0x7fbc1a40a5e0'Submit']-(8)-[UICollectionView:0x7fbc1b825800]   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x61000009b710 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fbc1a40ae80]-(0)-[UIButton:0x7fbc1a40a5e0'Submit']   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x61000009b760 V:[UICollectionView:0x7fbc1b825800]-(20)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fbc1a40b580]   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800009af40 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UIView:0x7fbc1a50d210.height == 568   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000009a950 UICollectionView:0x7fbc1b825800.height == 589   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2017-07-21 10:34:14.457 demo[2783:104307] *** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _dequeueReusableViewOfKind:withIdentifier:forIndexPath:viewCategory:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3600.7.47/UICollectionView.m:5115
2017-07-21 10:34:14.499 demo[2783:104307] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a16eb0b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000107414141 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a172cf2 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98
3   Foundation                          0x0000000106fae536 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 193
4   UIKit                               0x000000010822cea3 -[UICollectionView _dequeueReusableViewOfKind:withIdentifier:forIndexPath:viewCategory:] + 1991
5   UIKit                               0x000000010822d2fb -[UICollectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:] + 169
6   demo                                0x0000000106e2e7d6 _TFC4demo20SecondViewController14collectionViewfTCSo16UICollectionView13cellForItemAtV10Foundation9IndexPath_CSo20UICollectionViewCell + 150
7   demo                                0x0000000106e2eaf7 _TToFC4demo20SecondViewController14collectionViewfTCSo16UICollectionView13cellForItemAtV10Foundation9IndexPath_CSo20UICollectionViewCell + 87
8   UIKit                               0x0000000108218925 -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:isFocused:notify:] + 446
9   UIKit                               0x0000000108218761 -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:] + 35
10  UIKit                               0x000000010821d9bd -[UICollectionView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 4764
11  UIKit                               0x000000010822338e -[UICollectionView layoutSubviews] + 313
12  UIKit                               0x00000001079a955b -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1268
13  QuartzCore                          0x000000010cf38904 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
14  QuartzCore                          0x000000010cf2c526 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 370
15  QuartzCore                          0x000000010cf2c3a0 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
16  QuartzCore                          0x000000010cebbe92 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 294
17  QuartzCore                          0x000000010cee8130 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 468
18  QuartzCore                          0x000000010cee8b37 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 115
19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a114717 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a114687 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
21  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a0f9038 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 440
22  UIKit                               0x00000001078e008f -[UIApplication _run] + 468
23  UIKit                               0x00000001078e6134 UIApplicationMain + 159
24  demo                                0x0000000106e319a7 main + 55
25  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010b10e65d start + 1
)
```

I'm programming an app in swift and when I run the test app on the iPhone simulator everything works, but it crashes and shows this error report in the console log.Another thing is that I just created two view controller in my app and I have designed collection view in it. In first view controller its woring but in second view controller my collection view is not working.

Comment: Your Collection view  width and  UICollectionView Height is conflicting either remove it or give it low priority

Comment: Constraints can't make app crash, they are just ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'could not dequeue a view
>   of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier cell - must
>   register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype
>   cell in a storyboard'

That message tells us the crash occurs where you call `dequeueReusableViewOfKind` because you didn't first register a view as section header or footer. You must make sure that when you setup the collection view you also register header/footer to (either with `xib` or a class) to the collection view

For header:

with class

```
collectionView.registerClass(YourHeaderClass.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "yourReuseIdentifier")
```

with xib

```
var headerXib = UINib(nibName: "YourHeaderXib", bundle: nil)
collectionView.registerNib(headerXib, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: yourReuseIdentifier)
```

For footer:

with class

```
collectionView.registerClass(SupplementaryViewClass.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter, withReuseIdentifier: yourReuseIdentifier)
```

with xib

```
var footerXib = UINib(nibName: "YourFooterXib", bundle: nil)
collectionView.registerNib(footerXib, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter, withReuseIdentifier: yourReuseIdentifier)
```